# Hyper-V: Delete snapshot fail, invalid state

Tags: hyper-v

The drive the VM's are running on have run out of space and this caused all my VM's to go into Paused-Critical state.

To free up some space I want to delete some snapshots I took.  Where my snapshot is extended from the main VM with the Now (green arrow) extending the snapshot.

When I try to delete the snapshot I get the following error.

```
Failed to perform the operation. The virtual machine is not in a valid state to perform the operation.
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I was attempting to do the exact same thing and had that error. After which the VM's virtual network adapter had managed to disable itself for that VM and so all users lost connectivity with the server. Required a shutdown of the VM and re-enable the virtual network adapter to resolve. So beware of this. Not sure if the problem exists with SCVMM though?

Answer (score 0):

Try exporting your VM to another location with enough space.  I was able to recover a paused VM after I clicked snapshot by mistake and ran out of space.  After the export, I deleted the VM from the Hyper-V Manager and recreated/imported the VM.